# How to split a SUM column based on another BIT column?

Tags: mysql, select, mysql-5.7, subquery, pivot

MySQL v5.7
Having this table:

```
id   | sprId    | load    | calc
-----|----------|---------|---------
   1 |        1 |       1 |       7
   2 |        2 |       1 |       1
   3 |        2 |       1 |       4
   4 |        2 |       0 |      11
   5 |        3 |       1 |       2
   6 |        3 |       0 |      85
   7 |        4 |       1 |       1
   8 |        4 |       1 |      13
```

`load` is BIT.
How to split `calc` column sum based on the `load` column value, and then group by `sprId`.

I'm trying to get results like

```
 sprId    | sum_calc_load0  | sum_calc_load1
----------|-----------------|-----------------
        1 |               0 |               7
        2 |              11 |               5
        3 |              85 |               2
        4 |               0 |              14
```

Right now I'm doing two queries, and works, but I know for sure it can be done with subqueries, something I don't know that much.

Comment: See pivot tag, `GROUP BY` and `SUM`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sprId, 
       COALECSE(SUM(calc*(1-load)), 0), 
       COALECSE(SUM(calc*load), 0)
FROM source_table
GROUP BY sprId
```

Comment: COALESCE() will return the first NOT NULL value, isn't it?

Comment: @Kondybas That's true. OP have not provided DDL, so I assume that `calc` or `load` is nullable.

Comment: That is, if both columns are `NOT NULL`, the `COALESCE is unnecessary.